# No me anda mi funcion editar en PHP + SQL

Tags: php, sql

estoy haciendo un trabajo practico y no puedo hacer funcionar a mi función editar, creo que seguí bien los pasos que hay que hacer en cada parte y cuando cargo los datos y toco el botón editar me reedireciona a mi BASE_URL pero no se edita ni en el view ni en la base de datos... Alguno tiene idea por que puede llegar a ocurrir? Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!Gracias!
Intente rehaciéndolo y me sigue pasando lo mismo...

```
Controlador: 
<?php

require_once './app/models/games.model.php';
require_once './app/views/games.view.php';


class GamesController {
private $model;
private $view;

public function __construct() {

$this->model = new GamesModel();
$this->view = new GamesView();
   



}

public function Show() {

$gamestotal = $this->model->getAll();
$this->view->Show($gamestotal);

}


function add() {

$nombre = $_POST['Titulo'];
$fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
$precio = $_POST['Precio'];
$genero =$_POST['Genero'];

$id = $this->model->Insert($nombre,$fecha,$precio,$genero);
header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
}



function delete($ID_Juego) {

   $this->model->DeleteByID($ID_Juego);
   header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
}

function Edicion (){ 
       $this->model->editarByID($_POST['ID_Juego'], $_POST['Nombre'], $_POST['Precio'], $_POST['Fecha'], $_POST['Genero']);
       header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
     }




   }
  
 

VIEW:

<?php

class GamesView {


   function show ($games) {
       include './templates/header.php';
       include './templates/form_alta.php';
       
       echo '<ul class="list-group">';
       foreach ($games as $game) {
          echo "<li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
                   <span> <b>Juego:  </b>$game->Nombre - <b> Fecha de Lanzamiento: </b>$game->Fecha <b> - Genero : </b>  $game->Genero  - <b>  Edad: </b> +$game->edad - <b> Precio: </b> $$game->Precio</span> 
                   <a href='delete/$game->ID_Juego' type='button' class='btn btn-danger ml-auto'>Borrar</a>
                   <a href='edit/$game->ID_Juego' type='button' class='btn btn-primary ml-auto'>Editar</a>

               </li>";
       }
       echo "</ul>";
   
       include './templates/footer.php';
   }










}

model:

<?php 

class GamesModel {

private $db;

public function __construct() {
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;'.'dbname=tpe;charset=utf8','root','');

}


function getAll() {

$query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT juegos.*, generos.Edad as edad FROM juegos JOIN generos ON juegos.genero = generos.genero');
$query->execute();
$games = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

return $games;

}

function Insert ($nombre,$fecha,$precio,$genero) {

   $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO juegos (Nombre,Fecha,Precio,Genero) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
   $query->execute([$nombre,$fecha,$precio,$genero]);
   
   return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}

function DeleteByID ($ID_Juego) {
$query = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM juegos WHERE ID_Juego = ?');
$query->execute([$ID_Juego]);

}


function editarByID($ID_Juego, $nombre, $precio, $genero, $fecha){
   $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE juegos SET Nombre = ?, Fecha = ? , Precio = ?, Genero = ? WHERE ID_Juego = ?");
   $query->execute([$nombre, $fecha, $precio, $genero, $ID_Juego]);
 }

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en tu contexto?

Comment: Hola!! En donde lo tendría que colocar?

Comment: Al inicio de `function Edicion () {` ahí estás intentando recoger datos de `$_POST`, pero, ¿y si no refieres correctamente a los datos o el `$_POST` está vacío?

Comment: No me imprime nada, será por que no le esta llegando nada al POST?

Comment: Deberías ver aunque sea `null` o algo. ¿No ves nada? ¿Quizá tu código ni siquiera está llamando a ese método?

Comment: array(0) { } es el error que me tira el var dump y ademas me dice que no me reconoce ningun parametro

Comment: Si sale `array(0) { }` es porque el POST está llegando vacío, revisa la forma en que pasas los datos al servidor. Pon también un `var_dump($_GET);`, no sea que los datos estén pasando por GET.

Comment: array(1) { ["action"]=> string(7) "edit/16" } el dump del get me tira ese error y que me faltan todos los parametros igual..

Comment: No veo claro cómo estás mandando los datos, ¿es a través de los botones, en `delete/$game->ID_Juego` y `edit/$game->ID_Juego`? ¿Verificaste que `$games` tiene datos en ese contexto. Estamos ante un problema básico de depuración. Mira los días que llevas perdiendo tiempo con algo simple, todo por no depurar el código adecuadamente.

Comment: Los mando a través del boton generado y routeado delete/edit... Si games tiene los datos por que si no no me los mostraría y me muestra todo perfecto cuando lo recorro con el foreach... Perdón no estoy muy familiarizado con la depuración, me recomendas que me baje uno con php y me dirá el problemas mas especifico? Gracias...